# Extract subtitles in time range using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, subtitles

I have original video (with subs) and cropped version of it (without subs). I need to add subtitles from original video into cropped in appropriate time range.

I think the best way to do is:

1. Extract subtitles from `$start` to `$end`. I found this command `ffmpeg -i Movie.mkv -map 0:s:0 subs.srt`. But

- I don't know how to specify time
- Will data in subs.srt be correct? Since I want to add subs to cropped vesrion, time of all subs needed to be `$original_time - $start`.
- It extract only one track

2. Add subs.srt to cropped video.

Answer (score 0):

The `-ss` and `-to` flag specifies start time and end time in format hh:mm:ss. Here goes the code

```
ffmpeg -i original_video.mp4 -ss <start time> -to <end time> -c:s copy cropped_sub.srt
```

This extract first subtitle stream in between start and end time in cropped_sub.srt. And now combining cropped files.

```
ffmpeg -i cropped_video.mp4 -i cropped_sub.srt -c copy cropped_combined.mp4
```